# Changing the text of a UITextView from one view to another

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a problem with my code. When I type in a UITextField in another view controller the value is saved in a variable (var oraDa: String!). I would like to change the text of a UITextView if the text typed is nil or is not nil. Here's the code:

```
var oraDa: String!
var oDF: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    oDF = "From "

    if oraDa == nil {

        oDF = nil

    }

    finalText.text = "\(oDF!)" + "\(oraDa!)"

}
```

I want that when

> oraDa != nil

oDF is equal to "From"

but if oraDa is nil, oDF is equal to nil

Comment: This is kind of confusing. What do you mean by "when oraDa is empty"? What's the difference between "empty" and "nil" in your case?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry is the same thing sorry, I edited the question

Comment: This still doesn't make sense to me. You are saying that you want  oDF to equal "From" when oraDa == nil, but then you say that you want oDF to be equal to nil when oraDa is nil in the next line. They are the same thing. Are you saying you want to test for the string value of "nil"?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry You're right, I changed the question another time... so sorry

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Just one last thing, what if I had to add other parameters to 'finalText'? For example 'finalText.text = "(intestazione!)" + "(oDF!)" + "(oraDa!)"'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:
`finalText.text = "\(oDF!)" + "\(oraDa!)"` you are force unwrapping these string optionals. If they are `nil` then your code will crash.

If you are taking `oraDa' in from another view, then you should do your logic as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if oraDa == nil || oraDa == "" {

       oDF = nil
       finalText.text = "";
   } else {
       oDF = "From "
       finalText.text = "\(oDF!)" + "\(oraDa!)"
   }
}
```

Comment: Dang, beat me to it

Comment: Just one last thing, what if I had to add other parameters to 'finalText'? For example 'finalText.text = "\(intestazione!)" + "\(oDF!)" + "\(oraDa!)"'?

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Have fun coding!

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own question about how to add other parameters:

```
var intestazioneF: String!
var oDF: String!

if intestazione == nil || intestazione == "" {

        intestazioneF = ""

    } else {

        intestazioneF = "\n \n"
        finalText.text = "\(intestazione!)" + "\(intestazioneF!)"

    }

if oraDa == nil || oraDa == "" {

        oDF = nil

    } else {

        oDF = "From "
        finalText.text = "\(intestazione!)" + "\(intestazioneF!)" + "\(oDF!)" + "\(oraDa!)"

    }
```

and if you want to add even another parameter:

```
var intestazioneF: String!
var nomeFestaF: String!
var oDF: String!

if intestazione == nil || intestazione == "" {

        intestazioneF = ""

    } else {

        intestazioneF = "\n \n"
        finalText.text = "\(intestazione!)" + "\(intestazioneF!)"

    }

if nomeFesta == nil || nomeFesta == "" {

        nomeFestaF = ""

    } else {

        nomeFestaF = "\n \n"
        finalText.text = "\(intestazione!)" + "\(intestazioneF!)" + "\(nomeFesta!)" + "\(nomeFestaF!)"

    }

if oraDa == nil || oraDa == "" {

        oDF = nil

    } else {

        oDF = "From "
        finalText.text = "\(intestazione!)" + "\(intestazioneF!)" + "\(oDF!)" + "\(oraDa!)"

    }
```

Hope this will help other people

Thanks to Billy Caruso